# Magento 2 Rest Api V1/products missing extension attributes

Tags: magento2, products, rest-api, cataloginventory

I am calling the Rest API V1/products to get the product list from Magento 2 store

Request:

```
 http://{myMagentohost}/Magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1
```

Response:

```
 {"items": [ { "id": 1,"sku": "24-MB01","name": "Joust Duffle Bag","attribute_set_id": 15,"price": 34,"status": 1,"visibility": 4,"type_id": "simple","created_at": "2017-06-13 09:36:11","updated_at": "2017-06-13 09:36:11","product_links": [{"sku": "24-MB01", "link_type": "upsell","linked_product_sku": "24-MB03","linked_product_type": "simple","position": null,"extension_attributes": []},{"sku": "24-B01","link_type": "upsell","linked_product_sku": "24-WB04","linked_product_type": "simple","position": null,"extension_attributes": []}],"options": [],"tier_prices": [],"custom_attributes": [{"attribute_code": "description","value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - ot in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>"},{"attribute_code": "image","value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"},{"attribute_code": "small_image","value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"},{"attribute_code": "thumbnail","value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"},{"attribute_code": "url_key","value": "joust-duffle-bag"}]}],"search_criteria": {"filter_groups": [],"page_size": 1,"current_page": 1},"total_count": 2046}
```

Now according to the Magento 2 Rest API [swagger](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) documentation, 
catalogProductRepositoryV1, GET /V1/products in response it shows the extension_attributes but when I actually call this api from postman extension_attributes is missing.

I  search for it but no appropriate solution is available.

Can anyone help in this matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you do not have permission to see any extension attributes so it's left empty or omitted entirely?

For example, if your `extension_attributes.xml` looked like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="stock_item" type="Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface">
            <resources>
                <resource ref="Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory"/>
            </resources>
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Only admins with the `Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory` permission will see a `stock_item` key in the API response.

```
{
  "sku": "tshirt1",
  "price": "20.00",
  "description": "New JSmith design",
  "extension_attributes": {
    "logo size": "small",
    "stock_item" : {
      "status" : "in_stock"
      "quantity": 70
    }
  },
  "custom_attributes": {
    "artist": "James Smith"
  }
}
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html#ext-auth

Comment: I have an extension with all possible permission and it is still not listing it in /V1/products endpoint

Answer (score 0):

It is an open issue, you can track the issue [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8700).